# Make a custom setting to check for getting data from different websites

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, customsetting

I have developed an application in which I am getting data from a website using its API and storing it in salesforce. Now I want to add some more websites as options by using checkboxes. If I select two checkboxes, Then I can get data of those two websites and store the data in salesforce.

Is it possiblke in salesforce to do like this?

I want to get idea if it is possible.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways of doing this. You can use either `apex:inputcheckbox` or `apex:selectoption` in combination with `apex:selectcheckbox` to collect multi-select lists of data not related to an object Id. You'll want these to be inside of an `apex:form` tag. Your controller can look for `selected` to collect the checkboxes that have been selected and relate the information within your controller. Depending on the implementation, you may need to encase all of your functionality inside of a wrapper class.

Search on these tags in the forum and you'll find examples with code of how this can be accomplished. Also look at the [VisualForce Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm) which has some example code for building SelectOptions.

Comment: I would add that if you're going to be doing callouts, first get all your callout data and THEN save into the database. Doing a Save before a callout would prevent that callout from running (because you would've started a transaction)

Comment: We have to do these in some custom object I think. Am I right?

Comment: It depends. If you're going to be adding and removing different sites, then you'd want to do it using a custom setting unless you have a huge number of them. If it's a fixed length list of sites that you don't intend to change, you can just initialize them in your controller by adding them to a variable of type string and using split() to create an array of strings (or simply creating an array - your choice).